# SEOmoz shows 10k+ crawl errors - 302 redirect issue, magento 1.6 and 1.7

Tags: magento, seo, web-crawler

I have an SEOmoz account PRO and after adding the campaign and few days, crawls stats came in and with that 10k 302 redirects that shouldn't be there, there are URLS like compare product pages, enable-cookies URLs, etc. which are right now 302 that I need to get to 301. I am using magento 1.6 and on another store with 1.7 version of magento both have the same issue.

I actually followed this :

app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Response/Http.php

But there is no 302 or 301 on that file what should I do? I have like 10,000 redirect crawl errors which needs to be 301 they are currently 302.

Answer (score 0):

Check your cannonical url settings. Maybe MOZ massed out when see cannonical url errors.